# React Native styling header with Background Image

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, styled-components

I need some help. I am trying to style a screen header with an image in the background. But the background graphic is not styling properly, I have tried using both, `Image` and `ImageBackground`. The image should fit the width and should be in the background.

this is how it should look:
[image]

this is how it looks now:

[image]

when I set the width to 100% or to the width of the window this is what I get, The image gets cropped from the bottom:

[image]

Here is my code:

ArtistProfile.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Content } from "native-base";
import styled from "styled-components/native";
import ScreenLayout from "../layout/ScreenLayout";

interface ArtistProfileProps {
  componentId: string;
}

class ArtistProfile extends Component<ArtistProfileProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScreenLayout componentId={this.props.componentId}>
        <ArtistProfileContent>
          <HeaderBackground
            source={require("../../assets/img/header-bg.png")}
          />
        </ArtistProfileContent>
      </ScreenLayout>
    );
  }
}
export default ArtistProfile;

const ArtistProfileContent = styled(Content)`
  flex: 1;
`;

const HeaderBackground = styled.Image`
  flex: 1;
  align-self: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
`;
```

ScreenLayout.tsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import theme from "../../theme/Theme";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components/native";
import { Container } from "native-base";
import FooterNavigation from "../../components/footer/Footer";

interface ScreenLayoutProps {
  componentId: string;
}

class ScreenLayout extends Component<ScreenLayoutProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <ScreenLayoutContainer>{this.props.children}</ScreenLayoutContainer>
        <FooterNavigation componentId={this.props.componentId} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
export default ScreenLayout;

const ScreenLayoutContainer = styled(Container)`
  flex: 1;
`;
```

Comment: Try putting width: WINDOW.width, height: WINDOW.height to your image css

Comment: @UgurYilmaz well it is React Native can I still access WINDOW?

Comment: it won't work with window

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set width like this

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
```

[react native dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

Comment: If it doesn't work in your ArtistProfileContent, maybe you should find the parent tag's style to find out the limit at outside.
Try to add background color in different tag (use different color will be fine)and you will see the problem.
If background in ScreenLayout is full width of screen, the problem must in ArtistProfile, or is in ScreenLayout. Something like that

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already tried using the Dimensions it gets full width but the bottom waves get cropped. And yes the ScreenLayout is full width

Comment: the bottom waves get cropped>> Maybe you can add a little margin or padding at bottom to fix it?

Comment: add paddingbuttom:15 or marginbuttom:15 in style to try?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width to '100%' in HeaderBackground component.

Comment: when I set the width to 100% or to the width of the window the image gets cropped from the bottom. And also  this image should be in the background so I can place components on top of it.

Comment: Try to use an inspector element in your simulator or app though, so that you can easily find where that gap is happening. This is a good practice look at UI issues regarding unnecessary margin and spacing. @MusayyabNaveed

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/H1QhAPcUL   Look at this expo example on snack. Its simple to do with just View and button. Please look at the styles also.